# Aditional levels in PDF bookmarks

Tags: sectioning, bookmarks

I'm a novice in LaTeX and I use that code for having more sectioning levels, but when exporting to PDF the bookmarks of aditional levels are placed incorrectly. Does anyone know how can I place the bookmarks correctly?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\level[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\expandafter\chapter\or
    \expandafter\section\or
    \expandafter\subsection\or
    \expandafter\subsubsection\else
    \def\next{\@level{#1}}\expandafter\next
  \fi}
\newcommand{\@level}[1]{%
  \@startsection{level#1}
    {#1}
    {\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newdimen\@leveldim
\newdimen\@dotsdim
{\normalfont\normalsize
 \sbox\z@{0}\global\@leveldim=\wd\z@
 \sbox\z@{.}\global\@dotsdim=\wd\z@
}

\newcounter{level4}[subsubsection]
\@namedef{thelevel4}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{level4}}
\@namedef{level4mark}#1{}
\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*4+\@dotsdim*1+6pt\relax}}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*5+\@dotsdim*2+6pt\relax}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*6+\@dotsdim*3+6pt\relax}}
\@namedef{l@level4}{\@dottedtocline{4}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*7+\@dotsdim*4+6pt\relax}}

\count@=4
\def\@ncp#1{\number\numexpr\count@+#1\relax}
\loop\ifnum\count@<100
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\newcounter{level\@ncp{1}}[level\number\count@]
    \noexpand\@namedef{thelevel\@ncp{1}}{%
      \noexpand\@nameuse{thelevel\@ncp{0}}.\noexpand\arabic{level\@ncp{1}}}
    \noexpand\@namedef{level\@ncp{1}mark}####1{}%
    \noexpand\@namedef{l@level\@ncp{1}}%
      {\noexpand\@dottedtocline{\@ncp{1}}{0pt}{\the\dimexpr\@leveldim*\@ncp{5}+\@dotsdim*\@ncp{0}\relax}}}%
  \x
  \advance\count@\@ne
\repeat
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{100}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{100}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\level{0}{abc}\thispagestyle{empty}
\level{1}{abc}
\level{2}{abc}
\level{3}{abc}
\level{4}{abc}
\level{5}{abc}
\level{6}{abc}
\level{7}{abc}
\level{8}{abc}
\level{9}{abc}
\level{10}{abc}
\level{11}{abc}
\level{12}{abc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the work is already done. It remains the definition of `\toclevel@level<num>`
inside the loop:

```
\noexpand\@namedef{toclevel@level\@ncp{0}}{\@ncp{0}}%
```

`hyperref` already defines:

```
\def\toclevel@chapter{0}
\def\toclevel@section{1}
\def\toclevel@subsection{2}
\def\toclevel@subsubsection{3}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{4}
\def\toclevel@subparagraph{5}
```

The full example file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{open,numbered}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\level[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\expandafter\chapter\or
    \expandafter\section\or
    \expandafter\subsection\or
    \expandafter\subsubsection\else
    \def\next{\@level{#1}}\expandafter\next   
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\@level}[1]{%
  \@startsection{level#1}%
    {#1}%
    {\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% 
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}

\newdimen\@leveldim
\newdimen\@dotsdim
\begingroup
  \normalfont\normalsize  
  \sbox\z@{0}\global\@leveldim=\wd\z@
  \sbox\z@{.}\global\@dotsdim=\wd\z@
\endgroup

\newcounter{level4}[subsubsection] 
\@namedef{thelevel4}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{level4}}
\@namedef{level4mark}#1{}
\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*4+\@dotsdim*1+6pt\relax}}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*5+\@dotsdim*2+6pt\relax}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*6+\@dotsdim*3+6pt\relax}}
\@namedef{l@level4}{\@dottedtocline{4}{0pt}{\dimexpr\@leveldim*7+\@dotsdim*4+6pt\relax}}

\count@=4
\def\@ncp#1{\number\numexpr\count@+(#1)\relax}
\loop\ifnum\count@<100
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\newcounter{level\@ncp{1}}[level\number\count@]
    \noexpand\@namedef{thelevel\@ncp{1}}{%
      \noexpand\@nameuse{thelevel\@ncp{0}}.\noexpand\arabic{level\@ncp{1}}}
    \noexpand\@namedef{level\@ncp{1}mark}####1{}%
    \noexpand\@namedef{l@level\@ncp{1}}%
    {\noexpand\@dottedtocline{\@ncp{1}}{0pt}{\the\dimexpr\@leveldim*\@ncp{5}+\@dotsdim*\@ncp{0}\relax}}%
    \noexpand\@namedef{toclevel@level\@ncp{0}}{\@ncp{0}}%
  }\x
  \advance\count@\@ne
\repeat
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{100}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{100}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\level{0}{abc}\thispagestyle{empty}
\level{1}{abc}
\level{2}{abc}
\level{3}{abc}
\level{4}{abc}
\level{5}{abc}
\level{6}{abc}
\level{7}{abc}
\level{8}{abc}
\level{9}{abc}
\level{10}{abc}
\level{11}{abc}
\level{12}{abc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]